Decode a solana message signed via sign-offchain-message in a nodejs app
Trying to verify wallet ownership using a message signed by solana sign-offchain-message in a nodejs app, this code keeps saying invalid signature:
  const { encodedMessage, pubkey, message } = req.body;
  try {
    const publicKey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(pubkey);
    const header = Buffer.from('\xffsolana offchain\x00\x00', 'utf8');
    const messageLength = Buffer.alloc(2);
    messageLength.writeUInt16LE(message.length);
    const formattedMessage = Buffer.concat([header, messageLength, Buffer.from(message, 'utf8')]);
    
    // Assuming encodedMessage is the signature
    const signature = bs58.decode(encodedMessage);

    
    const isValid = nacl.sign.detached.verify(formattedMessage, signature, publicKey.toBuffer());
    if (!isValid) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid signature' });
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('err: ', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error verifying signature' });
    return;
  }



You should not create a Buffer using utf8 encoding because in utf8 encoding \xff requires two bytes, whereas in ascii it only needs one byte. The prefix \xffsolana offchain for Solana signing messages is implemented in Rust and should be 16 bits, so the correct approach would be to change your code to:
const header = Buffer.from('\xffsolana offchain\x00\x00', 'ascii');

wow, you're amazing. thank you!
